# Understanding Schematic utilizing step-up transformer

Tags: transformer

I have the following schematic. It's designed to step-up voltage and frequency, in range of ~10kV and 20KHz, from 230Vac-50Hz, but I have problems in understanding it. In [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Z1M.png) the box for transformer with 8 pins is shown in the other attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYHBW.png) . Transformer is having a feedback winding on top of primary winding, and two secondary windings.

I tried to simulate it in Proteus and NI Multisim, but both of them crashed. I know that the schematic is correct and working, but I cannot understand it. For instance, I don't know what is the usage of C1, C6, C7 & C8. Also, R2, R3, R4, R5, X1 and DZ1. After D1, voltage is half-rectified, but I don't know when C1 charges and discharges, or when X1 (Thyristor) is conducting and when Q1 (IGBT) is turned on and off and when the signal is taking the path through R4 or R5. what is the use of transformer feedback pins (pins 3 and 4)? Is there anyone who could help me? Can you simulate this schematic in any software?

Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Utme.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please embed your schematic and image into the post using the image upload button. That way we don't have to follow a link, we can read the text at the same time as viewing the image and the question will still make sense if the link dies. Thanks.

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @Transistor, I embedded the images and added the editable schematic to the post.

Comment: "but both of them crashed"  Crashed how?  Do you mean actually crashed, closed all the windows, and (if you poked that deep) left a report of a core dump in a log someplace?  Was there an error message?  Or did they freeze, or did your simulated variables go to maximum, or what?

Comment: What did you use for a transformer model?